# pip upload script or module

Tags: python, pip

I am sorry in advance if this is a duplicate of another question (and this is my first question here :) )

I would like to know if we can upload scripts to pip rather than packages.
I am currently writing a code and would like to make it available to the community through pip but I am not sure if this is possible...

When I say package I mean something that we can call inside another code with

```
import blabla
```

And script something that we can call from the terminal like any other program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload scripts, but you have to package them if you want to make it available to the community through a `pip install`.  That means you'll need to write a `setup.py` file, too.

```
# my_script.py
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the setup file:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['my_script=my_script:main'],
    },
)
```

There is other stuff you'll need to learn about to upload your script to the Python package index.  Check out a packaging guide, such as [PyPI Quick and Dirty](https://hynek.me/articles/sharing-your-labor-of-love-pypi-quick-and-dirty/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a package using a script then put this script inside the base folder:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
def install(package):
  import importlib.util
  if package in sys.modules:
    print(f"{package!r} already in sys.modules")
  elif (spec := importlib.util.find_spec(package)) is not None:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,'-m','pip','install', package])
  else:
    print(f"can't find the {package!r} module")
def build():
  required_packages=['wheel','twine','setuptools']
  for package in required_packages:
    install(package)
  if not os.path.exists('replit.nix'):
    os.system('cls')
  else:
    os.system('clear')
  path='SECOND_FOLDER/setup.py'
  os.system(f'python {path} sdist bdist_wheel')
  os.system('twine upload dist/*')
build()
```